# make date to ISO wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

when I do  `dateAdded : new Date().toISOString()` in a js file to create JSON file for data to import to mongo it shows up as `2016-11-26T21:51:23.879Z` in the mongo shell. I wanted it to look like `ISODate("2016-11-26T21:51:23.879Z")`.

I had to do something like the following to change it to the ISO wrapper that I commonly see.

```
Comps.find({category : "Consumer Electronics"})
    .then(function(comps){
        console.log(comps.length)
        comps.forEach(function(e){
            console.log(e.name)
            e.dateAdded = new Date(e.dateAdded.toString());
            // e.category = "Auctions";
            e.save(function(error, doc){
                if(error) console.log(error);
                console.log("doc saved : " , doc.name, " ", doc.category, " " , doc.dateAdded);
            })
        })
    })
```

`

Is there something I can do in the JS file to make the date show up in mongo right away with the ISO wrapper?

In my code above a query by `Consumer Electronics` but it seems that I want to query by date.

for example if i just imported 300 documents and I had 1000 in there already I want to be able to query by the dates that started 1001. I want to query by dates but I would feel better if it had the ISOwrapper and I don't want to query by category.

I have this in mongoose Schema  `dateAdded : {type : Date, default : Date.now},` I've been using mongoimport lately so I don't think that even matters.

Answer (score 0):

The `toISOString()` function will by definition return a String, as defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

You can store a Date object in mongo without transforming it :

```
 e.dateAdded = new Date();
```

Comment: I know I could store a date like that but I don't think it would show up with an ISO wrapper when I query the DB after I import the new data. That's why I played around with `toISOString()` . to see if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

When we use **Date()** , it returns date as **String**, However to return **ISODate** object you can use following overloaded date formats.

```
new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>") which returns the ISODate with the specified date.
new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>") which specifies the datetime in local datetime and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>") which specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
```

for more details please review [mongod-Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Date/)

Comment: I think those are just applicable to mongo shell. I don't think you can use them in your java script.

Comment: I believe this behaviour is driver specific, have you found the solution ?